# C# Open but closed principle for parsing

Tags: c#, design-patterns

What should I use for custom parsing to provide extensibility without having to inherit?  In other words, I am looking for the IFormatProvider (used for output) equivalent for parsing of a custom object.

Opposite of the following code:

```
var str = String.Format(new MyFormatProvider(), "{0:custom}", obj);
```

where `MyFormatProvider` implements `IFormatProvider`

Comment: Could you show code that you want to extent without inheritance?

Comment: Added an example.  I am not at a computer at the moment, so I may have gotten the syntax wrong.

Comment: @Patrick What's the *open-closed* part of your question? Don't see how it is related to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Open/Closed](http://www.oodesign.com/open-close-principle.html) basically just says that new or changed behaviors should be add-able without modifying existing code. In OOP, that's generally done with either inheritance or interfaces (a special kind of "inheritance").

You'd need to be a little more specific with your problem domain for a more specific answer, but as an example using interfaces would be something like:

```
 interface IObjectParser {
     object Parse(object obj, propertyName string);
 }

 class ReflectionParser : IObjectParser {
     public object Parse(object obj, propertyName string) {
         return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetMethod().Invoke(obj);
     }
 }

 object parsedValue = new ReflectionParser().Parse(new MyClass(), "MyProperty");
```

Then, if we wanted to added a new type of parser:

```
 class DatabaseParser : IObjectParser {
     public object Parse(object obj, propertyName string) {
         return ExecuteQuery(
            --Note the potential for SQL injection
            string.Format("SELECT {1} FROM {0} WHERE Id = @id", obj.GetType().Name, propertyName),
            ((dynamic)o).Id
         );           
     }
 }

 object parsedValue = new DatabaseParser(new MyClass(), "columnName");
```

This isn't really particular to open/closed, but since you brought up `IFormatProvider` it uses another technique to tunnel a variable number of parameters in the format string while still adhering to strong typing.

I'm not sure if there's a canonical name for it, but I refer to it as "stringly typed" (you can do the same with an array of objects, etc. - but using a `string` is fairly common and makes a good pun). You can see this type of API in things like JavaScript's [window.open windowFeatures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) and MVC's [HtmlHelpers htmlAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493049(v=vs.118).aspx) (which uses an anonymous type to the same effect),  I'd say it's actually an *anti-pattern* in most cases since it's breaks Liskov Substitution Principle, but it does have it's niche uses.

`IFormatProvider` (technically, `ICustomFormatter` does this part, and `IFormatProvider` is the factory) has to support an unknown number of possible formats. To do that, it tunnels any custom formatting instructions after the ":" - it's expected that the appropriate `ICustomFormatter` will know what to do with the values.

An example of that in the `IObjectParser` case would be something like:

```
 class ByteArrayParser : IObjectParser {
     public object Parse(object obj, propertyName string) {
         var bytes = obj as byte[];
         // we've tunneled multiple parameters in the propertyName string
         var nameParameters = propertyName.Split(":");
         // note we've lost our strong typing, and coupled ourselves to the propertyName format
         int index = int.Parse(nameParameters[0]);
         string readAsType = nameParameters[1];

         using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
         using (var br = new BinaryReader(ms))
         {
             ms.Position = index;
             switch (readAsType) {
                 case "float":
                     return br.ReadSingle();
                 case "int":
                     return br.ReadInt32();
                 case "string"
                     // we can even have yet another parameter only in special cases
                     if (nameParameters.Length > 2) {
                        // it's an ASCII string
                        int stringLength = int.Parse(nameParameters[2]);
                        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(br.ReadBytes(stringLength));
                     } else {
                        // it's BinaryReader's native length-prefixed string
                        return br.ReadString();
                     }
               default:
                     // we don't know that type
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("type");
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

When using this class, you have to specially format your `propertyName` in a way that can only be discovered through documentation (just like `String.Format`).

```
 // note again, we have to know ByteArrayParser's specific format and lose strong typing
 object parsedIntValue = new ByteArrayParser().Parse(myBytes, "4:int");
 object parsedSingleValue = new ByteArrayParser().Parse(myBytes, "4:float"); 
 object parsedStringValue = new ByteArrayParser().Parse(myBytes, "4:string"); 
 object parsedAsciiStringValue = new ByteArrayParser().Parse(myBytes, "4:string:15");
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head!  That was exactly what I was looking for :).  Thanks!